# Modular arithmetic terminology

Tags: terminology, modular-arithmetic

In division, we have terms like divisor, dividend, quotient, remainder. Do we have like terms for modular arithmetic? In particular, in the following, does $n$ have a special name such as "modulator" or something?

$$a \equiv b \quad (\text{mod}\: n)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normally called the [modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_relation).